# Getting only desired properties from nested array values with jq

Tags: json, field, filtering, jq

The structure I ultimately want would be:

```
{
  "catalog": [
    {
      "name": "X",
      "catalog": [
        { "name": "Y", "uniqueId": "Z" },
        { "name": "Q", "uniqueId": "B" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what the existing structure looks like except there are *many* other properties at each level (https://gist.github.com/ajcrites/e0e0ca4ca3a08ff2dc401ec872e6094c). I just want to filter those out and get a JSON format that looks specifically like this.

I have started out with: `jq '.catalog'`, but this returns only the array. I still want the `catalog` property name there. I can do this with `jq '{catalog: .catalog[]}`, but this prints out each catalog object individually which makes the whole output invalid JSON. I still want the properties to be in the array. Is there a way to filter specific property key-values within arrays using jq?

Comment: show the desired output for your current input. Besides, the input is not valid json: it can't have such notation `"name": "Y"` within an array

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that is the desired output. The input is the same, it just has more properties. I've included a sample in the question

Comment: I have a solution which gives the expected output. But I can call it a "hack", not a universal approach. That's why I didn't post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following transforms the given input to the desired output and may well be what you want:

```
{catalog}
| .catalog |= map( {name, catalog} )
| .catalog[].catalog |= map( {name, uniqueId} )
| .catalog |= .[0:1]
```

However, it's not clear to me that this is really what you want, as you don't discuss the duplication in the given JSON input.  So maybe you don't really want the last line in the above, or maybe you want duplicates to be handled in some other way, or ....

Anyway, the trick to keeping things simple here is to use `|=`.

An alternative approach would be to use `del` to delete the unwanted properties (rather than selecting the ones you want), but in the present case, that would be (at best) tedious.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what `|=` does?

Comment: .a |= X is like the assignment: .a = (.a | X).  See the manual for details.  You might also like to use https://jqplay.org/

Comment: This gave me what I needed; sorry for being a little bit unclear. Actually the `|= map()` is most of what I needed and it makes sense with your explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using **tostream** to convert your `sample.json`
into a stream of [path, value] arrays as you can see by running

```
jq -c tostream sample.json
```

This will generate

```
[["catalog",0,"catalog",0,"name"],"Y"]
[["catalog",0,"catalog",0,"prop11"],""]
[["catalog",0,"catalog",0,"uniqueId"],"Z"]
[["catalog",0,"catalog",0,"uniqueId"]]
[["catalog",0,"catalog",1,"name"],"Y"]
[["catalog",0,"catalog",1,"prop11"],""]
...
```

**reduce** and **setpath** can be used to convert back into the
original form with a filter such as:

```
reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
  {};
  setpath($p;$v)
)
```

Adding conditionals makes it easy to omit properties at any level.
For example the following removes leaf attributes starting with "prop":

```
reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
  {};
  if $p[-1]|startswith("prop")
  then .
  else setpath($p;$v)
  end
)
```

With your `sample.json` this produces

```
{
  "catalog": [
    {
      "catalog": [
        {
          "name": "Y",
          "uniqueId": "Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "Y",
          "uniqueId": "Z"
        }
      ],
      "name": "X"
    },
    {
      "catalog": [
        {
          "name": "Y",
          "uniqueId": "Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "Y",
          "uniqueId": "Z"
        }
      ],
      "name": "X"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to remove certain properties, then one could do so using `walk/1`.  For example, to remove properties whose names start with "prop":

```
 walk(if type == "object" 
      then with_entries(select(.key|startswith("prop") | not)) 
      else . end)
```

The same approach would also be applicable if the focus is on retaining certain properties, e.g.:

```
walk(if type == "object" 
     then with_entries(select(.key == "name" or .key == "uniqueId" or .key == "catalog"))
     else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build up a file that contains paths into the json (expressed as arrays) that you want to keep.  Then filter out values that do not fit in those paths.

paths.json:

```
["catalog","name"]
["catalog","catalog","name"]
["catalog","catalog","uniqueId"]
```

Then filter values based on their paths.  Using streams is a great way to go for this since it gives you access to these paths directly:

```
$ jq --slurpfile paths paths.json '
def keep_path($path): any($paths[]; . == [$path[] | select(strings)]);
fromstream(tostream | select(length == 1 or keep_path(.[0])))
' input.json
```

Comment: I tried using `fromstream` in my solution but it didn't return anything (actually the only time `fromstream` has worked for me in the past was when I used it along with `truncate_stream`) but I observe you're careful to include the `length == 1` paths which my reduce select(length == 2) discards.  I've never understood why `tostream` generated those `length==1` paths but I think I know now.

Comment: The length 1 entries denote the end of a definition of the corresponding object or array. Without those entries, fromstream won't know when to close off the corresponding value. Anything left open will be omitted from the result. At least, that's how I understand it. Streams in jq was always a big question mark to me, I still have yet to know enough about it to use it effectively.

Comment: Also, based on what I'm seeing on how the streams are created, it makes most sense when the root is an array. Otherwise, the last item of the stream doesn't make sense with what the data looks like. Empty objects and arrays are also very weird. I'm not sure how to interpret those results.